# visual studio testing capabilities

Tags: visual-studio, testing

I am looking to find out the testing tool capabilities that are offered with Visual Studio.  From my research, I understand that you offer both functional and load testing tools for both web and Windows-based applications.  I read the ‘coded UI Tests’ feature automates UI testing.  My questions is, does this feature only work on .NET-based applications or can I use it to do UI testing on an application that was written in PowerBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx) the configurations that are supported by coded UI.

PowerBuilder is not in the list but depending on the technology it relies on (MFC?) it might work.

You can download a trial version of VS and try it on a PB application.